# Workaround for MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() on Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: .net, linq, generics, reflection, compact-framework

I want use a Linq IQueryable Toolkit in project on .NET Compact Framework.
The Linq capabilities in CF is little bit shapred - i.e.: IQueryable interface is not available. So I've found third party libraries, which implements missing functionality what I need.

Now I have problem with missing method "MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()". There is cca 100 methods, which uses this method. So I don't need the exact clone of "GetCurrentMethod()". The workaround way for this specific case is enough.

Sample of original code:

```
public static bool Any<TSource>( this IQueryable<TSource> source ) {
    return source.Provider.Execute<bool>( Expression.Call( null, ((MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()).MakeGenericMethod( new Type[] { typeof( TSource ) } ), new Expression[] { source.Expression } ) );
}

public static bool Any<TSource>( this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate ) {
    return source.Provider.Execute<bool>( Expression.Call( null, ((MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()).MakeGenericMethod( new Type[] { typeof( TSource ) } ), new Expression[] { source.Expression, Expression.Quote( predicate ) } ) );
}
```

The posibile solution is replace "(MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()" with specific method call. For example: GetMethod_Any_TSource_On_Source() and GetMethod_Any_TSource_On_Source_With_Predicate_TSource_Bool().

I search for some handy solution how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/3c958ba2-fb35-4c77-987c-520dd6338c90)

It is essentially impossible in plain managed code in Compact Framework 1.0.

In 2.0 is it possible but error prone, fragile and most importantly NOT guaranteed to be correct (a serious flaw).

I would suggest instead writing a macro which can find all instances of "((MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod())" and determinte the method in which they reside.

Simply converting every line like so

```
".*\(\(MethodInfo\)MethodBase\.GetCurrentMethod\(\)\).*"
```

to
throw new Exception((MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()).Name);

- Compile for the non compact framework (fixing by hand the locations that the regex replace broke, there shouldn't be many)
- Run every method in the classes where replacements happened by reflection
- catch the resulting exceptions and print the message (method name) and the first line of the stack trace.

This then gives you a list of what you need to put in directly at each call site (probably backed up by a lazily created static field holding the MethodInfo for each one.

This is cumbersome but might work reasonably well as a one off action pre framework update though to be honest it might be just as quick to go through and do it by hand.

Comment: +1

Thank you very much for reply.

Actualy I've rewrite all ".GetCurrentMethod" as "((Func<T1, T2, ...>)%TypeName%.%MethodName%).Method". It was a lot of work, but the performance is better than calling ".GetCurrentMethod" and it works. I had luck, that I required used it only in static methods, so rewriting it was not so complex.

The way with throwing exception is realy awkward, and it kill a performance, if it is used frequently. But thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Cool, did you do it by hand or use a tool? If by a tool perhaps you could add that as an answer (and accept it) since it would be useful to others.

Comment: I did it by hand, because there was used generics in classes and methods a lot.

Actually I did it already almost, as you wrote. So ok, I can accept your answer.

Comment: OK thanks, if you had any info or recommendations feel free to edit my answer as you like.